# Who was this famous man and what did he say?

Tags: cipher, history

My eccentric great uncle passed away, and included a provision in his will that I should receive his entire estate If I can prove myself by breaking his encryption. He claims to be the descendant of a famous person from history. This is some kind of test to prove that I'm worthy, I suppose.

All the provision says is:

*There once lived a famous man named*

**1B2F213831A3 13B8F5FD387**

*who famously wrote*

**12 2580D83 35D4CDED 42C 8FC6 A CE0DC796D 174560 B39E6 17F 2FCD6A87F96D 70DF**

*If you are worthy of my fortune, you will be able to crack this code. You have exactly 20 hours from this moment to turn in your answer to my executor. Good luck!*

Needless to say, I'm quite nervous right about now. Can you help me solve this puzzle?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The man is

> Alexander Hamilton

and he said:

> I never expect to see a perfect work from an imperfect man

which we find by

> converting the numbers from base 16 to base 36

Comment: Wow that was quick! Nice work!!

Comment: I suppose +20 hours was a hint? :)  Nice job @will